# android and Google Maps : fingerprint for device

Tags: android, google-maps

I am developing sample application that uses Google Map API. I have generated Google Map key and applications runs good on emulator on local machine. But when I run same on my android device (phone) map is not generated. There are only grid lines. I suppose this is a problem related to Google map key i am using.
How can I get key that runs on any map enabled android device ?

I am using API 10 and Android 2.3.3 and same is compatible with the device.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map key is associated with your app signing certificate. If you generate a map key using the credentials of the certificate you use to sign the app, it should work on any android device.

Answer (score 0):

singn the apk with 'key for publish' and map key must be built with fingerprint from the 'key'

Answer (score 0):

I suposee that when You deploy app on emulator You use development cert, but on device You deploy with other cert. Fingerprint for GMaps is generated for cert, not for device.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check you have included the following tag in you application tag

Also make sure you are debugging/running the application from the same workstation which was running your map fine incase of debug.keystore.

If you are signing your application, then you will have to use that keystore (used in case of signing), to get the Map API key and then put it in the respective map layout.xml.